# How to clear the timezone associated with a moment-timezone object

Tags: moment-timezone

Using `moment-timezone`, if you have a moment object set with a timezone e.g. `moment.tz('America/New_York')`, how can you clear the timezone and change the moment to "local" time?

Notably, `moment.local()` does not work (a subsequent call to  `moment.tz()` still equals `America/New_York`). I can confirm that my local time is not `America/New_York`.

The only solution I have found is to set an invalid timezone, e.g. `moment.tz('local')`. This logs a warning to the console that you have attempted to set an invalid timezone (annoying), but it does clear the timezone associated with the moment object, returning it to a local moment object. The warning that `moment-timezone` spits out emphasizes that this solution may break in the future though, and it's obviously a hack.

What's the proper way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Update

This issue was caused by a bug in `moment-timezone`. As of version, [0.5.24](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/blob/develop/changelog.md#0524-2019-04-17), `moment.local()` should correctly clear the time zone associated with a `moment-timezone` object.

#### Original

At the...moment! This appears to be a bug in `moment-timezone` (see [#738](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/738), [#258](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/258#issuecomment-147492280)). The current work-around I've found is to first use `moment.utc()` (which clears the timezone and also sets the moment in "utc" mode) and then `moment.local()`. I.e. `moment.utc().local()`.